# Полоска пластика для упаковывания хлеба

Tags: названия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется пластиковый ошейник на целлофановом пакете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Производители упаковки называют этот элемент **фиксатором-зажимом** или просто **зажимом** (иногда **клипсой-зажимом**). http://upakovka-i-tara.ru/fiksatory-zazhimy-dlya-paketov.html